# Problems Connecting to Active Directory Using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, active-directory

I have been tasked at work to authenticate my "rails 3 app" with our Active Directory(Windows 2003), before accessing certain pages.

I decided to use "devise_ldap_authenticatable", but can't seem to get it to work properly.

I keep getting redirected to the login page with the following error message showing in the logs.

"Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms"

Do I have to change the devise email field to a user-name in order for it to connect successfully?

Has anyone got a working config I could can look at?

My ldap.yml consists of the following:

```
development:
  host: myip
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName 
  base: cn=Users,dc="mydomain",dc=uk,dc=com  
  admin_user: user
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
```

my devise.rb consists of the following:

```
config.ldap_logger = true
config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
config.ldap_ad_group_check = false
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
config.reconfirmable = true
```

my routes.rb consists of the following:

resources :posts
   devise_for :users
   root :to => 'posts#index'
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

Comment: Sometimes when connecting with AD it is necessary to specify the domain.

Comment: Maybe try appending the domain like so "mydomain\\user"

Comment: Hi Imran I have tried that and still no luck :(

Comment: Ah OK, what error message do you get when you enter the wrong password or username? Also with regard to the domain, a shot in the dark but try changing the backslashes to forwardslashes.

Comment: Imran, I can now connect and authenticate, but is there a way to recursively search through sub OU's?